# Java - Overloaded method selection with extended type

Tags: java, compilation, overloading

I want to understand the logic behind this code:

```
public class AA
{
    private int num;

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public int getNum() {

        return num;
    }

    public AA(int num) {

        this.num = num;
    }

    public int f(AA val)
    {
        num = val.num;
        return num;
    }

}
```

class BB:

```
public class BB extends AA
{

    public BB(int num) {
        super(num);
    }
    public int f(BB val)
    {
        setNum(val.getNum()*2);
        return getNum();
    }

}
```

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    AA y1 = new BB(2);
    BB y2 = new BB(3);

    System.out.println(y1.f(y2));
```

why the output is 3 and not 6?

EDIT - I know that is not overriding. My question is why it didn't invoke BB's f? I sent BB variable. not AA.

I understand if at compile time it'll choose the A's f but after that it needs to choose B's f.

I tried to add this to AA and it printed 6..

```
    public int f(BB val)
    {
        System.out.println("Im here");
        num =1+ val.getNum()*2;
        return num;
    }
```

Comment: OK. what is your question?

Comment: `f(BB)` overloads, not overrides `f(AA)`

Comment: I know that. I sent BB type - why it didn't invoke the one with BB parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method overriding,

```
public int f(AA val)
```

and

```
public int f(BB val)
```

don't have the same signature .

When you call `y1.f(y2)`  (`y1` being of type `AA` and `y2` of type `BB`) :

`AA` doesn't have a `f(BB)` method, so the closest one is called which is `f(AA)`, and `BB` doesn't override this method.

Comment: I know. but I send BB variable. Why it won't go to BB's f?

Comment: Because `AA` doesn't have a `f(BB)`  method, so the closest one is called, which is `f(AA)` .

Comment: I understand if this will be in the compile time. but why in running time it didn't changed? (just like with overriding when the compiler check if the have the function but the son's is the one that invoked..)

Comment: There is no overriding, and only one method in `AA` can match the `f(BB)` call. Since `BB` doesn't override this method, only the one in `AA` can be called .

Comment: Let me get things straight - the procedure is first choose the function IN AA that matches - and after that - choosing the override if it have one?

Comment: Yes, the first check is whether a method in `AA` matches. If there is one, check if the subclass type overrides this exact method (which is not the case here). If it does, call the subclass's method, else call the parent class method.

Comment: This piece of the puzzle that was missing for me... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you clearly are calling a function (f) from *y1* which is an *AA* reference type.